# multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

Tags: c++, warnings

I've seen several posts regarding this warning, but as far as I am aware none that address my issue.

I've declared this in my application:

```
    const unsigned char clsXMLnode::mcucAttrMacroDelimiter = '£';
```

This results in the compiler issuing two warnings:

```
   multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
   large integer implicitiy truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
```

But why the value is still within an unsigned char.

Adding a cast:

```
    const unsigned char clsXMLnode::mcucAttrMacroDelimiter = (unsigned char)'£';
```

Gets rid of the second warning, but why is it required and why does the first warning remain?

Comment: For reference, the UTF-8 representation of this character is C2 A3.

Comment: Is your source file Unicode encoded? If so that single char my be more than one.

Comment: According to this link (http://www.ascii-code.com/), the £ is part of the extended ASCII character set and the code is 163.

Comment: @SPlatten Depends on the encoding of your source file - check it with a hex editor - or some other program that can tell your its encoding.

Comment: The source file is plain text, there is no hidden encoding.  I'm developing on RedHat Linux 7.2 with QT5.6

Comment: @SPlatten OK but how hard is it to do `od -c file.cpp` to verify?

Comment: @sleep tight pupper, that shows nothing except a dump of the file and that doesn't have any encoding.  Just did it.

Comment: Text in a file *always* has an encoding.

Comment: Where is it then?  If there is encoding it is inherent in the application QtCreator.  However we are talking about C and text encoding should not enter into the language source file unless specified by the coder.

Comment: @SPlatten, How the text is stored in memory is determined by the encoding. If your file is being stored as bytes (like all things in memory), it will have an encoding that determines how to turn the characters into bytes. ASCII is one way to do that for byte values from 0 to 127, and extended ASCII is an older method of doing that for byte values of up to 255.

Comment: I don't care how it is stored in memory, this is the source file, the source is interpreted by the compiler, unless I specify that the source is to be interpreted in some way I expect the compiler to treat it as presented.

Comment: @SPlatten The compiler follows the rules of the language. `'£'` is of type *char* and will overflow because it's outside the range. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: QT Creator default file encoding is UTF-8. Source: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-options-text.html

Comment: type char is -128 to 127, where as an unsigned char is 0 to 255.  £ does not overflow and unsigned char.

Comment: @SPlatten, The compiler reads a file, which is a sequence of bytes in memory. The editor has to convert the characters to bytes for the compiler to read. I suspect, because of how common UTF-8 is and that its two-byte representation of this character lines up with the error message, that your file is encoded as UTF-8. The compiler also needs to know how to decode the bytes back into characters. Although it's unlikely you'll ever need to use it, GCC supports `-finput-charset=<encoding>` for this purpose.

Comment: @SPlatten Re-read what I wrote. `'£'` is of type char, not unsigned char. 163 - 256 = -93, which is what you get thanks to overflow.

Comment: I've been coding in C since 1987 and never have I had to concern myself with how the compiler might interpret the character set...I would understand if I had used some strange presentation of the data...but a byte is a byte and its size is well understood and documented.

Comment: @sleep right pupper, I changed my types from char to unsigned char because it wouldn't accept it in comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any clear explanation as to why this warning is produced and given that a character is supposed to be 8 bits, not 16.

Even a cast did not resolve, so I changed the character to one that didn't result in this error.